# Bower install anuglar-module is installs angular instead?

Tags: angularjs, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe) angular module (angular-stripe).  When I type `bower install angular-stripe` (as the docs recommend) I get:

```
bower angular-stripe#*          cached git://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe.git#4.1.0
bower angular-stripe#*        validate 4.1.0 against git://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe.git#*
bower angular-cookies#~1.3.11   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.3.12
bower angular-cookies#~1.3.11 validate 1.3.12 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.3.11
bower angular#1.3.12            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.12
bower angular#1.3.12          validate 1.3.12 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.12

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
1) angular#1.3.11 which resolved to 1.3.11 and is required by angular-animate#1.3.11, angular-cookies#1.3.11, angular-mocks#1.3.11, angular-resource#1.3.11, angular-route#1.3.11, angular-sanitize#1.3.11, angular-scenario#1.3.11, angular-touch#1.3.11, nightwalker 
2) angular#~1.3.2 which resolved to 1.3.11 and is required by angular-stripe#4.1.0 
3) angular#1.3.12 which resolved to 1.3.12 and is required by angular-cookies#1.3.12Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

This looks like I am installing angular all over again or something. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: try this command: `bower install angular-stripe --force-latest`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the resolution

```
 "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x"
  }
```

In your bower.json file